# Must a topological space with the following property be a manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

**Edit:** it has been pointed out to me that the original definitions I gave do not quite work. Here is the revised question:

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathscr{B}$ be a basis of $X$. For any subset $U$ of $X$, say that $U$ has an upper bound in $\mathscr{B}$ if there exists $B\in \mathscr{B}$ such that $U\subseteq \overline{B}$. Say that $B'\in \mathscr{B}$ is a least upper bound of $U$ if $U\subseteq \overline{B'}$ and for all $B\in \mathscr{B}$, if $U\subseteq \overline{B}$ then $B'\subseteq B$. Say that $\mathscr{B}$ has the least-upper-bound property if every subset of $X$ which has an upper bound in $\mathscr{B}$ has a least upper bound in $\mathscr{B}$.

Say that $X$ is $\mathscr{B}$-dense if, for any pair of elements $x, y \in X$, the set $\{x, y\}$ has a nonempty least upper bound $B\in \mathscr{B}$, such that $x, y \not\in B$.

I believe that $\mathbb{R}^n$ given the standard basis of open balls should satisfy both these properties—unless I have gotten something wrong somewhere, which is eminently possible.

Now, onto the actual question: suppose that $X$ is a second-countable Hausdorff space, for which there exists a basis $\mathscr{B}$ such that $\mathscr{B}$ has the least-upper-bound property and $X$ is $\mathscr{B}$-dense. Is $X$ necessarily a manifold?

Apologies if this question is rather trivial.

Comment: Am I right to think that if such were a manifold, it would have to be a $1$-manifold, since an $n\geq1$-manifold could not possibly be $\mathscr{B}$-dense? I'm imagining that you can't make any open ball closed by adding $2$ points, and the open balls are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Can you give any example of such a topology? At first, I thought $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology and the basis of bounded open intervals, but that doesn't satisfy the least upper bound property.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oh, you're right. In fact, I think that suffices to prove that such a space $X$ cannot be a manifold. Suppose it were. Every topological manifold is metrizable. Look at any singleton $\{p\} \subset X$. It is clearly bounded, but also clearly has no least upper bound since $\{p\} \subset B_r(p)$ for all $r > 0$.

Comment: At this point, I can only think of discrete topologies with a basis consisting of the singletons and the empty set. (But do bases allow the empty set? They certainly don't require the empty set. The empty set is only need for the least upper bound for $U=\emptyset.$

Comment: Maybe you want the least upper bound property only for $U$ open in $X?$ Then the real line with the basis of bounded open intervals works.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, there's an omission in my comment. What my comment actually shows (if I'm right) is that such a space must have the discrete topology since we can still have a least upper bound on a singleton with the discrete metric ($B_{\frac{1}{2}}(p)$ suffices). In other words, the only manifolds with the given properties are $0$-manifolds. It can easily be checked that they do have the desired properties.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews can you explain why it doesn't? If $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ is contained in a bounded open interval $(a,b)$, then $U$ is bounded, and so has a GLB and a LUB in the usual sense. Call them $a'$ and $b'$. Then $(a', b')$ is a least upper bound of $U$ in the sense given here. Unless I am mistaken.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh yes, I meant to specify that $U$ had to be open. Let me fix that.

Comment: Ok, I revised the definitions a bit and I believe they should apply to all $\mathbb{R}^n$ now.

Comment: Do you have any examples of nonempty spaces satisfying your conditions?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I believe they should be satisfied by $\mathbb{R}^n$. They're supposed to, at least, and if they don't I've gotten something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Any reason behind this belief? Did you try the $n=0$ case?

Comment: I think if $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the open balls satisfies this condition then $\mathbb{Q}^n$ should also? I haven't checked this carefully though.

Comment: As a rule, leaving our deleted section only adds noise to your question. If you **must** keep that text around, put it at the end, don't leave it at the beginning. Start your question with the important stuff, not your mistake crossed out. @M.Sperling

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah ok, I will fix that.

Comment: In fact, the only topological space satisfying your condition is the empty set.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Surely it's satisfied by $\mathbb{R}$ under the standard basis of open intervals. If $U$ is contained in an open interval $I$ then $U$ is bounded, so it has an infimum $a$ and a supremum $b$. Then $(a, b)$ is a least upper bound of $U$, in the sense that it's a basis element whose closure $[a, b]$ contains $U$, and any basis element $(a', b')$ whose closure contains $U$ must contain $(a, b)$ (following from the definition of inf and sup). So $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies this formulation of the LUB property.

Comment: It also satisfies the density property: for every pair of elements $a, b$, the set $(a, b)$ suffices as a non-empty basis element, not containing $a$ or $b$, that forms a least upper bound of $\{a, b\}$.

Comment: What possible reason is there to believe this is true?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a T1 topological space (every singleton is closed). Let ${\mathcal B}$ be your basis of topology on $X$; for $x\in X$ set ${\mathcal B}_x:= \{B\in {\mathcal B}: x\in B\}$. Since $X$ is T1,
$$
\bigcap_{B\in {\mathcal B}_x} B =\{x\}. 
$$
Note that each singleton $\{x\}\subset X$ has an upper bound (since ${\mathcal B}$ is a basis of the topology of $X$).
Now, suppose that $B_x$ is a least upper bound of a singleton $\{x\}\subset X$. Since each $B\in {\mathcal B}_x$ is an upper bound of $\{x\}$, it follows that $B_x\subset B$ for all $B\in {\mathcal B}_x$. Since $X$ is T1,
$$
B_x\subset \bigcap_{B\in {\mathcal B}_x} B =\{x\}.$$
Since $B_x$ cannot be empty (as you require $\{x\}\subset \overline{B_x}$), it follows that $B_x=\{x\}$.

Since $B_x$ is open, $X$ has discrete topology. Consider now a subset $\{x,y\}\subset X$. Since you did not assume that  $x\ne y$, we can as well take $x=y$. As I noted earlier, the unique least upper bound $B_x$ of $\{x\}$ is $\{x\}$. But then $x\in B_x$, contradicting your 2nd condition.

Thus, we proved that each T1 space satisfying your axioms is empty.